# How can Picard proved that his method was right?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In order to solve initial value problems ..
We know that Picard's method is right , 
but i need to know how can Picard proved this ?

Comment: You can find a proof in many textbooks on differential equations. Commonly, [Banach's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) is used in these proofs. You can also have a look at the beginning pages of [my notes](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/dynsys/) that I wrote for a course on dynamical systems some years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y^\prime(t)=f(t,y(t))$, we have that $\int^x_{x_0}y^\prime(t)dt=\int^x_{x_0}f(t,y(t))dt$. This means that $y(x)=y(x_0)+\int^x_{x_0}f(t,y(t))dt$. We have:
$$y_{n+1}(x)=y(x_0)+\int^x_{x_0}f(t,y_n(t))dt\\
\implies y(x)=y(x_0)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^x_{x_0}f(t,y_n(t))dt\\
\implies y(x)=y(x_0)+\int^x_{x_0}f(t,y(t))dt$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: Note that this a sketch, not actually a proof. for the full proof you must prove that the sequence $y_n$ actually converges under certain circumstances.

Comment: @nbubis Yes, that is true. I'll add that in later, when I have some time.